# listview popup in Xamarin.android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have thoroughly searched already and then decided to ask here. I am trying to find an example of implementing a `button` when a user clicks, `listview` appears and when user clicks the `button` again, the `listview` disappears in xamarin.android

Answer (score 1):

1. Keep a variable to control wheter the ListView is visible or not.
2. Make your activity implement `Android.Views.View.IOnClickListener`.
3. Make the click of your button change the visibility of your ListView

   ```
   private bool _isShowing = false;

   //Don't forget to initialize those in your OnCreate 
   private ListView _listView;
   private Button _button;

   public void OnClick (View v)
   {
       _isShowing = !_isShowing;
       _listView.Visibility = _isShowing ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Gone;
   }

   //Inside your OnCreate, after initializing you button and your ListView
   _button.SetOnClickListener(this);
   ```

To use a smooth animation, simply add this to your .axml:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

I strongly suggest using a MVVM approach, but since you didn't mention any frameworks, this will work just fine